# windows getpixel from game window

Tags: c, windows

I want to get pixel color from specified game window(game can be written using d3d or opengl) and then process it in my c code. WinApi GetPixel() may not work. What should I do then? I want it to be as fast as possible.

Comment: Reading pixels is fundamentally slow. Your best bet is to redesign your program so it doesn't need to read pixels. For example, do hit testing on geometries rather than pixels.

Answer (score 0):

For Opengl, try `glReadPixels()`.